# How do I set up recurring donations?

Tags: payment

I'd like to be able to set up recurring monthly gift donations.  Is this possible with my CRM? Currently, we can accept one time gifts but can't seem to figure out how to take automatic monthly gifts.

Comment: You should explain which Payment Processor you are using as this is the key factor.

Answer (score 2):

In what part of the world are you located? If it is in Europe you might need the CiviSEPA extension as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

On any Contributions Page -> Contribution Amounts -> check the box labeled Recurring Contributions.

The details of how this will work depend on your Payment Processor.